# Django Migrations command workflow

Tags: django, database, migration

There are three migration commands in Django:

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`
3. `python manage.py syncdb`

In what order do these commands should be executed in terms of workflow of a basic project?

I am using Version: 1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`syncdb` is deprecated and does the same as `migrate`.

Whenever you make a change to your models, and when you first create them, each time you'd want to first run `makemigrations` to create the migration files, then `migrate` to apply them to your database.

Comment: Worth adding an extra clarification that the migrations created by `makemigrations` should be committed to your repo, then on deploy you only need to run `migrate` on your production machines.

Comment: How can `makemigrations` be seperately committed to the repo?